# Foreach в php/laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

Добрый день. Проблема такая. Есть таблица articles у которой приблизительная структура такая:

```
$table->string('title_ru');
$table->string('title_en')->nullable();
$table->text('content_ru');
$table->text('content_en')->nullable();
$table->.....
```

Не кидайтесь на меня я знаю что такое решение мало назвать костыльным, но суть вот в чем ->
В переменной $articles я храню все посты. Мне нужно в контроллере прочекать текущий язык и вывести в статью соответствующий title и content.
Чекать и менять язык на соответствующий я собрался так

```
if (App::getLocale() == 'ru')
{
   foreach($articles as $article)
   {
     $article['title'] = $article->title_ru;
   }
}
```

Все замечательно, только вот как сохранить данные изменения обратно в переменную $articles что бы передать во view и распарсить там тем же @foreach !? Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в корне неправильная логика мышления. Все эти манипуляции с языком делать в контроллере нет смысла, у ЛВ есть встроенные методы для работы с языками. Также хранить языковые настройки в бд нет смысла. В шаблоне, в том месте где текст, вы вставляете не переменную с текстом а что то на подобии {text | trans} это из symfony twig, но идея такая же. Шаблон будет подхватывать язык автоматически, для этого дополнительных действий не надо совершать. Файлы с переводами хранятся в проекте. Еще одно, в контроллере использование foreach это плохая практика.